# Multiple Websites with Multiple Sitemaps under single IIS Endpoint

Tags: seo, sitemap, url-rewriting, iis

We have multiple websites with different domains under single IIS endpoint. Each website has its own sitemap - *sitemap1.xml* and *sitemap2.xml*.

Can we implement rewrite rules so that `www.example1.com/sitemap.xml` will rewrite to `www.example1.com/sitemap.xml` and `www.example2.com/sitemap2.xml`?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow.  Are you saying you want to rewrite one URL to two different things?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have it like this and just inform webmaster tools about the different affiliation.

- `/sitemap1.xml`
- `/sitemap2.xml`

Another option is to use a rewriting mechanism to rewrite calls to the corresponding sitemap file. Using .htaccess or IIS-rewrite.

- `domain1.com/sitemap.xml` rewrites to `/sitemap1.xml`
- `domain2.com/sitemap.xml` rewrites to `/sitemap2.xml`

**IIS.net  URL Rewrite**
[IIS rewrite Information](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite)